# Looking for this Typeset

Tags: fonts, typography, preamble

I am writing my thesis and juggling around with different typesets in latex. I like this setting much (please see the picture below) but am 
not able to generate this using the standard packages.

Can anyone please tell me how to get this text and math typesetting.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It doesn't seem to be special. What did you try?

Comment: as you have the pdf you can easily find out exactly which fonts are used (font menu in acrobat or some other viewers or pdffonts commandline utility.

Comment: although you say in a (non-) answer that the output you get from the suggested code is lighter than the page you show in the example, that document class and fonts are almost certainly what produced the example page.  although the computer modern fonts *are* lighter than, say, times, the darkness of the resulting printout is very much dependent on the printer used.  similarly for the image on a monitor.  that is where adjustments would be most appropriate, but if that's not possible, it will most likely not be possible to match the example very closely.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Finally, the intertemporal wedge has the component
\begin{equation}
  C_t = R_t \left(1 - \mathbb{E}_t
  \left[ \frac{U_{c_t}}{R_t U_{c_{t+1}}} \right]
  \right).
\end{equation}
This term is a residual that picks up all reasons for distorting the savings
\dots
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Are you after Times New Roman?

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

should do the trick.  Otherwise, as someone noted above, you can look in the document you like and see what fonts it is using.

(Edit, as per comment below, thanks)

Comment: Well, `times` is an outdated package, I would not recommend it nowadays....If needed, suggest `mathptmx`